# Android - Adding a new Raw Contact and Data under an existing contact

Tags: android, contacts

I need to add a new data field to an existing contact from my application. My understanding is that I need to add a new RawContact for an existing contact and add a new Data row under the RawContact.

Have tried various options, but can't get it the right.

Here is what I need:
1. Use Contact Picker to select an existing contact.
2. Create new RawContact for the selected contact if the RawContact was not already created.
3. Create/Update the Data row under the RawContact and store the custom id for the contact.

Will be great if you can point me to an example for this.

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as easy as it could look. You need to implement your own sync adapter. You can follow the SampleSyncAdapter for that. As you will not be synchronizing with a backend server  you can get rid of all the JSON and networking stuff. You can also make the AuthenticatorActivity very simple with an almost empty onCreate method only.
Also consider that if you create a raw contact the user will be able to unlink the original contact and your rawcontat.

Are you sure you need to do it?

BTW do you need to store only an ID? In that case you can use the SourceID that is already available in the RawContacts table

Comment: I don't want the ID added via my app to be visible in the Contacts app. Do I still need to implement SyncAdapter? I have only one application specific ID to be added to a Contact. SourceID of an existing RawContacts or should I create new one? Will be great if you could post an example.